# Why I can't login to android studio with google account?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a very new to Android studio and Firebase.
I created and android project and tried to connect to Firebase. But I've encountered two problems.

1. After logging into my google account from Android studio by clicking the sign-in button on the upper right conner and successfully logged in through the browser, I can't see myself logged after returning to android studio and it still requires login.
   I tried using both chrome and Firefox all not working.
2. I tried create the project on Firebase and supplying all required files and SHA1 and successfully registered the project
   But when tried to create Real-time Database, it shows: AN Error has occurred.

I'm using windows10 64bit, android studio version 3.5.3, Firefox and chrome as browsers

what could be the problem? Can anyone help ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Check Android Studio log for errors. Help -> Show Log.

Comment: I suggest not using the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio (which is pretty broken), and instead following the instructions in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Comment: Thanks alot for the support sir,
But the problem of Android sigin still isn't working. I' have tried all ways and means to fix the problem but sill not working. including cache reset......
I just can't signin using the google account.  I can login through the browser, I can access firebase database.But can't connect with Android studio  to test my app.
Tis is my problem,..Any fixing suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks again. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Copy the callback-link, change https to http and paste it in firefox.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).